# Mapped types don't seem to work with generics

Tags: typescript

```
export type KeysOfType<Obj, KeyT> = {
    [K in keyof Obj]-?: Obj[K] extends KeyT ? K : never;
}[keyof Obj];

type Row<T> = T & { id: number };

export enum ColumnType {
    Node,
}

interface BaseColumn<T, ValidPropValue> {
    accessor: KeysOfType<T, ValidPropValue | undefined>;
    type: ColumnType;
}

export interface NodeColumn<T> extends BaseColumn<T, string> {
    type: ColumnType.Node;
}

interface Car {
    name: string;
    weight: number;
}

type CarRow = Row<Car>;
type CarNodeCol = NodeColumn<Car>;

const car: Car = { name: '', weight: 0 };
const carRow: CarRow = { name: '', weight: 0, id: 1 };

const carNameCol: CarNodeCol = {
    type: ColumnType.Node,
    accessor: 'name'
};

// works
const nameAccessor: 'name' = carNameCol.accessor;
const name: string | undefined = carRow[nameAccessor];

// doesn't work. should do exactly the same
const renderNode = <T>(row: Row<T>, column: NodeColumn<T>): string => {
    const accessor: KeysOfType<T, string | undefined> = column.accessor;
    const value: string | undefined = row[accessor]; // <--
    return value || '';
};

console.log(renderNode(carRow, carNameCol));
```

In function the value definition is marked by compiler as incorrect:

```
Type 'Row<T>[{ [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends string ? K : never; }[keyof T]]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type '{ id: number; }[{ [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends string ? K : never; }[keyof T]]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

It looks to me like `Row<T>` is wrongly substituted with `{ id: number; }` missing the `& T` part.

Is it a problem with my types, or is this a bug/limitation of the TypeScript compiler?

Comment: This seems [familiar](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728#issuecomment-479542352).  The summary is likely that the compiler just can't figure it out and that a type assertion is probably the way to go if you're sure your code is correct.

Comment: Typescript will not be able to follow that `KeysOfType` will only be the string keys `T`, just type assert.

Comment: @jcalz Same comment 22 secs apart, must be true  :))

Comment: Oh, that looks very similar to my case. Thank you guys, I wanted to be sure before playing -god- compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, the compiler just isn't clever enough to figure this out.  It's more of a limitation than a bug.  The easy way to deal with this is to embrace your mental superiority and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to calm the compiler down.

```
const renderNode = <T>(row: Row<T>, column: NodeColumn<T>): string => {
    const accessor: KeysOfType<T, string | undefined> = column.accessor;
    const value = row[accessor] as unknown as string | undefined; //  me smarter than compiler
    return value || '';
};
```

The other way to go is to lead the compiler through the steps of being sure about your types.  For example, you can make the annotated type of `row` explicitly require that it is not just `Row<T>` but also `Record<KeysOfType<T, string | undefined>, string | undefined>` (meaning something whose values at those keys are indeed `string | undefined`).  That's redundant in your mind, but it helps the compiler understand.  And the call should still work.

```
const renderNode = <T>(
  row: Row<T> & Record<KeysOfType<T, string | undefined>, string | undefined>,
  column: NodeColumn<T>
): string => {
    const accessor: KeysOfType<T, string | undefined> = column.accessor;
    const value: string | undefined = row[accessor]; // no error now
    return value || '';
};
```

Personally I'd use the assertion because the extra type baggage you have to carry around to appease the compiler wouldn't be worth it to me.

Hope that helps; good luck!